# Correct way of doing a safe copy from a range of kernel addresses that could contain invalid addresses?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I need to read from a kernel address called `myKernelAddress` to `myKernelAddress + size` and copy it to my buffer.
But the problem is that some addresses between `myKernelAddress` to `myKernelAddress + size` could be invalid. So my question is what is proper and safe way of doing this copy, which also saves me from a kernel panic? Do I need to manually check every address between  `myKernelAddress` to `myKernelAddress + size` with  `virt_addr_valid`, or is there a better way?

Comment: I would imagine any valid kernel address points to a whole page, so you would only have to check when you cross page boundaries,

Comment: This really looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why may the range contain invalid addresses to begin with? It looks like the problem is upstream. Where do you need to copy to (user or kernel space)? What is the use case? Can you show some code to give more context?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I need to dump some suspicious kernel memory, for example a possible rootkit, so I can find the start and end address of a this hidden kernel module, but some parts of it might be invalid. Why? I don't know.

Comment: Valid addresses have to have a valid MMU mapping. If the assumed rootkit written well, the proper solution is to low level programming of MMU in a non-race manner. Otherwise Linux page table might also not know about the validity of addresses. Saying that, what you need is a set of physical page addresses to copy. They can be make valid or checked via Linux MM.